# How long and how many CMSampleBuffer can I reference?

Tags: ios, swift

In apple iOS develop document: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturevideodataoutputsamplebufferdelegate/1385775-captureoutput

has:

> To maintain optimal performance, some sample buffers directly reference pools of memory that may need to be reused by the device system and other capture inputs. This is frequently the case for uncompressed device native capture where memory blocks are copied as little as possible. If multiple sample buffers reference such pools of memory for too long, inputs will no longer be able to copy new samples into memory and those samples will be dropped.

How long is `too long` in here? Can I get the real value by Swift?

I tried use camera to get CMSampleBuffers.